# What is a sufficient condition such that the graph of $f(\theta)$ in polar coordinates is symmetric relative to the $y$ axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Consider the function $f(x)$. The condition for the graph of $f$ in Cartesian coordinates to be symmetric about the $y$ axis is

$$f(x)=f(-x)$$

ie, $f$ is an even function of $x$.

Consider the graph of the function $f(\theta)$ in polar coordinates.

**What is a sufficient condition such that this graph in polar coordinates is symmetric relative to the $y$ axis?**

I am aware of two cases where this occurs:

1. $f(\frac{\pi}{2}+\theta)$ is even
2. $f$ is odd

Is there a general case?

Comment: Well, clearly, $f(\theta)=f(\pi-\theta)$ is necessary, but not sufficient. However, $f(\theta)=f(\theta+2\pi n)$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ is also necessary. I think these two conditions together are sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

You graph is symmetrical about the y-axis when $(x,y)\in G\implies (-x,y)\in G$.

Expressed in polar coordinates this means $\begin{cases}f(\theta_1)\cos(\theta_1)=-f(\theta_2)\cos(\theta_2)\\f(\theta_1)\sin(\theta_1)=f(\theta_2)\sin(\theta_2)\end{cases}$

Since we are not interested in $f=0$ which is automatically symmetric (since origin belongs to y-axis) we can simplify by $f$ to get the necessary condition:

$$\tan(\theta_1)=-\tan(\theta_2)\iff \theta_1\equiv-\theta_2\pmod\pi$$

And you get your conditions on $f$:

- $\theta_2=(2n)\pi-\theta_1\implies f(\theta_1)=-f(\theta_2)$
- $\theta_2=(2n+1)\pi-\theta_1\implies f(\theta_1)=f(\theta_2)$

Comment: Let's consider as an example the function $f(\theta)=1-\sin{(\theta)}$. The graph of this function in polar coordinates is symmetrical about the y axis. Let's check your conditions. $f(\theta_1)=1-\sin{(\theta_1)}$, $f(\theta_2)=1-\sin{(\theta_2)}=1-\sin{(-\theta_1)}=1+\sin{(\theta_1)}$. Take the negative of this expression and compare: $-f(\theta_2)= -1-\sin{(\theta_1)} \neq 1-\sin{(\theta_1)}=f(\theta_1)$. What am I missing?